# fmem compile error with make

Tags: linux, memory, compilation

I am a beginner in the Linux world and I'm trying to figure out how to run the `make` command. I'm trying to make use of `fmem` (memory dump tool), and it is said that "`make`" must be run from a terminal in the folder.

However I get this:

```
root@bakie:/root/Desktop/fmem/fmem_1.6-0# make
rm -f *.o *.ko *.mod.c Module.symvers Module.markers modules.order \.*.o.cmd \.*.ko.cmd \.*.o.d
rm -rf \.tmp_versions
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10-3-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [fmem] Error 2
```

I used `Debian (Kali ) 3.10-3-686-pae`

How can i solved this error to compile ?

Comment: `/home/tux/Documents/fmem/fmem_1.6-0` is this where your source code located which you are trying to compile?

Answer (score 1):

`fmem` is a module that get inserted into the kernel and through which you can access the `/dev/fmem` (substitute for `/dev/mem` which was discountinued from linux kernel 2.6 for security reasons).

Like any other kernel driver module, to compile it, you need to have the `kernel headers` which seem to be missing on your linux. See this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files) on how to install `kernel headers`. Once you have the `kernel headers`, it should compile fine.

Comment: That link pointed to me like that apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

In my case, apt-get install linux-headers-3.10-3-686-pae

It showed That there have not many deb files.

Still cannot not compile with make.

Comment: You won't be able to compile `fmem` without the kernel headers.

Comment: To get kernel headers I run  apt-get install linux-headers-3.10-3-686-pae  ( Failed t fetch and many errors )

How can i get for that ? please help me

Answer (score -1):

`make` command works if your current directory contains `Makefile` named file

Comment: The `Makefile` is obviously there

Comment: yes Makefile is obviously there, but I cannot work with make.